Ubuntu 20.04 Firefox 128 Audio levels shift when youtube plays ads
The title says it all. When I run youtube I inevitably have ads show up. I don't want to use an adblocker, I just want the audio to be the same no matter what is playing.

set up something like F9 as a media mute key in Settings -> Keyboard to kill the sound until the advert ends

What is your reason for not using an adblocker? [edit] in to your question. I use UBlock Origin with FF and its very effective and doesn't seem to affect performance.
